# Calculating order of element in quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-presentation, quotient-group

I need some solution verification on basic group theory. Let group $G$ be the quasidihedral group of order $16,$ i.e. the group presentation is:

$$G=\langle \sigma, \tau  \mid \sigma^8=1, \tau^2=1, \sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^3 \rangle $$

Now let $H=\langle\sigma^4\rangle $. This group is a normal subgroup of $G$, so we can think of the quotient group $G/H$. I need to calculate the order of the element in the quotient group, $\bar{\tau}\bar{\sigma} \in G/H$. I calculated the order of this element as
$$(\tau H\sigma H)^2=(\tau\sigma)^2H=\tau\sigma\tau\sigma H=\tau(\tau\sigma^3)\sigma H=\sigma^4 H$$
and as $\sigma^4 \in H$, the order of this element is 2.

Am I right? Are there any parts to be improved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The group _presentation_.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Sure.  May I ask, how do you know $H$ is normal?

Comment: I learnt that we only need to check the set of generators, so I checked whether $ghg^{-1} \in H$ for $g=\sigma, \tau, h=\sigma^4$. Is there an easier(or maybe direct?) way?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I'll take your word for it.  If so, you seem to be alright.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChrisCuster He's correct about normality.  Any element of $G$ can be expressed in the form $\tau \sigma^k$ so it's enough to confirm $\tau^{-1} H \tau = H$. The solution is correct.